# Access a Python variable which is inside a function, in another function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, variables

Let's say I have a function:

```
func1():
    do something
    a,b = somevalues,somevalues
```

Now let's say I have another function:

```
func2():
    do something
```

**I would now like to now use `a,b` in `func2()` which were calculated inside `func1()` .**

I tried using

```
func1():
    do something
    a,b = somevalues, somevalues
    func1.a = somevalues
    func1.b = somevalues

func1()
func1.a
```

**But using this, I have to each time run `func1()` before using `a,b`.**

`func1()` also creates some plots along with calculating `a,b`.

**So is it possible to utilise `a,b` in `func2()` without calling `func1()` ?**

Comment: Can you return `a,b` from `func1()` and then pass them as arguments to `func2()`?

Comment: @robert: I don't know!! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to rethink your code structure. If you need a and b independently of `func1()` then they should not be declared within it.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis: But I calculate them inside the `func1()` as I needed them for several plots inside `func1()`. So you are suggesting me to calculate them outside the function?

Comment: @ThePredator Yes, exactly. You could store them as member variables of a class, for example, if that makes sense given their meaning.

Comment: Your question is nonsensical. Why would you be able to use them before calling `func1`? Functions are not classes. You very much need to rethink how you are doing things.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis: If possible could you suggest me any links where I can read more about storing them as member variables of a class?

Comment: Ive never seen that contruct before, but maybe a generator would suit you? The variables within generator functions maintain their values in between calls.

Comment: @ThePredator It's not EXACTLY what you're looking for, but try reading my answer to a previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/27568860#27568860

Comment: But if `a,b` are calculated witin `func1`, how can you use them without calling `func1`? 'Utilize' them in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer by robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695386/2437514) is probably the easiest way to do what your want. Here is another:

```
class class1():
    a,b = somevalues, somevalues
    @staticmethod
    def func1():
        do something

func2(class1.a, class1.b)
class1.func1()
```

The reason this works and your way doesn't work has to do with the way Python treats functions and classes.

The body of a function is not executed until it is called the first time. So when you have:

```
def func1():
    func1.a = somevalue
```

...you cannot access `func1.a` until `func1` has been called at least once, as you have already discovered.

However, for classes, the body of the class runs when the code is compiled. So that when you do:

```
class example:
    a = somevalue
```

...you are able to access `example.a` immediately.

EDIT:

Answering the question in the comments: access `func1`, `a`, or `b` as shown above using the class itself (in Python, classes ARE objects, just like any other object):

```
class1.a
class1.func1()
```

You could also make a shortcut for yourself:

```
func1 = class1.func1
func1()
```

Another way to do things- so that you could have different versions of `a` and `b`- be to make `a` and `b` instance attributes instead of class attributes.

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b
    @staticmethod
    def func1():
        dosomething

obj1 = class1(somevalue1A, somevalue1B)
obj2 = class1(somevalue2A, somevalue2B)
func2(obj1.a, obj1.b)
func2(obj2.a, obj2.b)
obj1.func1()
obj2.func1()
class1.func1()
```

The last three lines all call the same function, because `obj1.func1`, `obj2.func1`, and `class1.func1` all point to the same method of `class1`. Note that the reason you can call `func1` from both the class (`class1`) and the instances (`obj1`, `obj2`) of the class is that `func1` is a static method.

Comment: I understand now! But in this case, how do I call `func1()` ? Do I need to use the `class` and call it or can I call it directly like `func1()` ?

Comment: You can use the class to call it since it is a static method of the class, or you can make an instance of the class. I'll add some more explanation.

Comment: @ThePredator I have answered your question in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I shall try to understand it slowly

Answer (score 5):

This may be what you want. Also, I suggest you work through an introductory Python tutorial.

```
func1():
    #do something
    a,b = somevalues, somevalues
    return a, b

func2(a, b):
    #do something on a and b

a, b = func1()
func2(a, b)
```

Comment: I accept this as an answer for now! But as pointed out by @michaelrccurtis, I shall try to restructure my code!

Answer (score 0):

```
func1():
    do something
    a,b = somevalues,somevalues
    return a, b

x, y = func1()
```

Now you can use `x` and `y` everywhere without callin `func1()` every time. For example in func2() this way:

```
def func2(a, b):
    do something
```

Then you call `func2()` with x and y respectivly:

```
func2(x, y)
```

Comment: but since `func1()` create many plots, I don't want to call `func1()` to access the variables as I need to then close all the plots!

Comment: Then why do you assign values to `a` and `b` in a function that draws a plot?